# Action in Internal transition does not save value of variable in DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

I have Internal transition with Action that sets value of variable

```
.and().withInternal()
.source(DETAILS_ERROR).event(VIEW).action(setReadTrue())

 private static Action<StatusId, ActionId> setReadTrue() {
    return context -> {
        Doc doc = Util.getDoc(context);
        doc.setRead(Boolean.TRUE);
    };
}
```

I check the code

1. set DETAILS_ERROR status
2. send VIEW event
3. Postman sends me the response read=true
4. ...and debugger tells me that read=true
5. but in db value has not changed(read=false)

If I use an External transition the value of the "read" variable in the database changes(read=true)

```
 .and().withExternal()
.source(DETAILS_ERROR).target(DETAILS_ERROR).event(VIEW).action(setReadTrue())
```

say me please, what wrong? i want use withInternal()

Comment: You're saying that using withExternal() is working and you're also saying "i want use withExternal()" - so what is the problem?

Comment: sorry, it is misprint.